# Cannot parse String with CET in Android SDK

Tags: java, android, date

I have a bunch of code that convert a String to a `Calendar` object and it is working properly in online compilers (Oracle JDK):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM DD HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
date.setTime(sdf.parse("Wed Feb 10 05:50:10 CET 2019"));
System.out.println(date);
```

But it's not working in the Android SDK. When I try to use the same code in one of my activities, I got:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Feb 10 05:50:10 CET 2019"
    at java.base/java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:395)
```

Any ideas, why it isn't working?

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with. And rock solid.

Comment: It may or may not be relevant for your issue: for day of month you need lowercase `dd` in the format pattern. Uppercase `DD` is for day of year.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `CET` zone abbreviation you probably want to use `z` instead of `Z` and change your pattern to `EEE MMM DD HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy`.

> **z** - Time zone General time zone   Pacific Standard Time; PST; GMT-08:00   1+
>
> **Z** - Time zone RFC 822 time zone   -0800

Comment: I tried using using `z` instead of `Z` but in vain, I'm getting the same error

Comment: @octopus will it work if you use `CEST` instead of `CST`? or change to `UTC`?

Comment: @octopus `CET` is an abbreviation, normally one should use `Europe/Paris` or `America/Los_Angeles`. I don't have Android SDK to test your code, maybe it's invalid zone name?

Comment: So if it was invalid, why does Oracle JDK accept it, and parse it without any issues ?

Comment: @octopus This might depend on the version of your android SDK, before N it wasn't based on OpenJDK. In short Android is not using exactly the same codebase as Oracle.

Comment: @octopus The time zone abbreviations are locale specific, and different Java versions use different locale data so may print and accept different abbreviations even for the same time zone and same locale You may try and see what you Android version *prints* from a `SimpleDateFormat` with time zone set to for example Europe/Berlin, Europe/Paris or Africa/Algiers.